# IMDB API request GraphQL Error 'ClientError: Cannot query field "Image" on type "MainSearchEntity"'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, graphql, imdb

I'm trying to get the top 10 movie name recommendations that match the search term 'Africa', based on the IMDB API demo here https://developer.imdb.com/documentation/api-documentation/sample-queries/search/?ref_=side_nav.

I need the query to return the movie id, title, image poster and filming location.

However, when I run the graph query below, I get the error 'ClientError: Cannot query field "Image" on type "MainSearchEntity".|Cannot query field "FilmingLocation" on type "MainSearchEntity"."

The query works fine when I remove the code `Image { url } FilmingLocation { text }` from the script.

What could be the problem with the query below?

How do I include the poster image and filming location in the query?

Thanks!

```
{
  # Get the top 10 name recommendations that match the search term Africa.
  mainSearch(
    first: 10
    options: {
      searchTerm: "Africa"   
      isExactMatch: false   
      type: TITLE      
      includeAdult:false,
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        entity {
          # For returned Names, get me the id, name text, image, year, country
          ... on Name {
            id
            nameText {
              text
            }
          }
          Image {
                  url
            }
          FilmingLocation {
                  text
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two fields that are causing you trouble are called posterImage and filmingLocation (usually field names are in camelCase), I guess your query should be:

```
query {
    # Get the top 10 name recommendations that match the search term Africa.
    mainSearch(
        first: 10
        options: {
            searchTerm: "Africa"
            isExactMatch: false
            type: TITLE
            includeAdult:false,
        }
    ) {
        edges {
            node {
                entity {
                    # For returned Names, get me the id, name text, image, year, country
                    ... on Name {
                        id
                        nameText {
                            text
                        }
                        image {
                            url
                        }
                        filmingLocation {
                            text
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem seems to be that the two fields were not inside the MainSearchEntity. Hope it helps!

Comment: The API says the names are Image and FilmingLocation. Using camel case on the fields gives an error. https://developer.imdb.com/documentation/api-documentation/sample-queries/search/?ref_=side_nav

Comment: I can't find the exact schema, so I can't say what the contents of the MainSearchEntity are (apart from the two we know from the example: id and nameText). Do you know where the full schema is?

Comment: This is the APIs Data Dictionary. https://developer.imdb.com/documentation/bulk-data-documentation/data-dictionary/?ref_=side_nav

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

Turns out the image poster field is 'primaryImage' not Image.

Here's the working code:

```js
{
  # Get the top 10 name recommendations that match the search term Jennifer.
  mainSearch(
    first: 10
    options: {
      searchTerm: "Jennifer"   
      isExactMatch: false   
      type: TITLE      
      includeAdult:false,
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        entity {
          # For returned Names, get me the id, name text, image, year, country
          ... on Title {
            id
            titleText {
              text
            }
            primaryImage {
              url
              }
            filmingLocations(first:1) {
              edges{
                node{
                  text
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```